# After 3.5.1. upgrade, posts appearing on Site yet *NOT* in WP admin!

Tags: posts, admin, upgrade

Upgraded to newest WP version yesterday and with that many of my posts disappeared from admin. However, they do appear fine online. If you go to link below, all posts on Projects section of site were previously IN admin. Clearly they exist somewhere, just not sure how to retrieve. I can see all associated keywords in admin (along w/ number of posts linked to keywords).

http://tri-lox.com/projects/

Any ideas how this might have happen and how I can reverse?

Pls help! Thanks.

Comment: You need to [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) and [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). Without this, impossible to answer.

Comment: Sorry, admittedly not code savvy here so not entirely sure what i need to debug based on those articles...

Comment: Check for PHP errors. I had some issue with PHP version and plugin updates when upgrading some old sites (deprecated functions)

Comment: How/where do I access WP Debug?

Comment: Add or find `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer (can't comment) but I had this happen with my pages recently. It turned out to be a naming conflict with a custom post type ( I used the word "order"). If you have made any CPT's check your names if the are really common words.

Here is a link to learn how to turn on debugging. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress